# Как сортировать ArrayList<String[]> obj

Tags: java, arraylist

Собственно, как сортировать Список по "полям" String[] - где obj.get(1)[0] - это - имя. obj.get(1)[1] фамилия и т.д.

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так

```
Collections.sort(obj, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
                int result = o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
                if (result == 0) result = o1[1].compareTo(o2[1]);
                return result;
            }
        });
```

или так (Java 1.8)

```
Collections.sort(obj, Comparator.comparing((String[] o) -> o[0]).thenComparing(o -> o[1]));
```